# Trouble connecting to a database not on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on php website for my class and I am having trouble connecting to my schools database server when i upload my files to my schools website.  My school only has a database server on HediSQL and Workbench and I am currently using HeidiSQL to access the account database my school created for me.

I am currently using this code to try and connect.

```
$host='school.edu';
$user='user';
$pass='pass';
$db='db';
$port='3306';
  mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);
```

Using this i can connect to my schools database just fine when i am on my own computer and run it through localhost, but as soon as i upload my website using SSH to my schools server, the website cannot connect to the database.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.
Edit: I am using php, heidiSQL, and SSH secure file transfer.

Comment: Any error message in `mysqli_error()`? In server error log? Are logins correct? Etc. Basic debugging. This code looks okay.

Comment: in the server where i uploaded my website it says.   Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in (pathway),  I haven't tryed mysqli_error yet.

Comment: If this works for you local DB but not for the hosted school one, then there is something different. Credentials? Port? Host name? DB Name? What errors does your connection throw?

Comment: the credentials i used were given to my by my schools websites admin, i haven't used heidiMySQL before so maybe something is off with my settings?

Comment: @harrison this suggests that your school does not have PHP's MySQLi module installed. Check by running `phpinfo()` in a script and see what modules are enabled.

Comment: @panther it's possible it's a recent version of PHP and maybe the school choose not to install MySQLi for some reason. Maybe they only allow PDO.

Comment: @Twisty yes i believe you're right, ill try use PDO to access my db.  Thank You.

Comment: `school.edu` how did you get this host ? Are you working local server or did you using any hosting services?

Comment: school.edu is just a madeup name to represent the school server.  I didn't want to reveal my actual school website.

Answer (score 1):

```
$host='localhost';
$user='user';
$pass='pass';
$db='db';
$port='3306';
mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);
```

Please make changes to the $host variable.

Answer (score 0):

$host = 'localhost';
host is always use as localhost on server